# creating a synced realm for all users

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I launched the object server (standard configuration running locally) and than in an iOS app i set the synced realm url to be "realm://localhost:9080/realms/shared-realm" and in the server output I see that not only the realm files are not created but also I see `debug: sync-server: Using already open Realm file: /Users/Shared/db/user_data/__admin.realm` an the objects that i add to the local realm in iOS are not synced over.

the user I'm using is not an admin.
thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

The `__admin.realm` file is an internal file used by the Realm Object Server. It doesn't necessarily indicate anything about the synchronisation status of your Realm files.

Why are you using the `9080` port? As far as I remember, it ought to be `8080`? By default, there is a "multiplexer" module that runs as part of the Realm Object Server which allows you to send both HTTP request and Realm Sync WebSocket connections directly to port `8080`, and the server will automatically redirect it to the correct endpoint, internally.

Port `8080` is important, because this is required for the authentication to work properly. I also believe that port `9080` is not listening on all interfaces by default, only `localhost`.

Comment: no, it listens to the 9080 port. the problem is that if I don't put the `~` char it wont create the realm ex. "realm://hostname:port/sharedRealm" if I put it everything works fine but only one user can interact with it ex. "realm://hostname:port/~/sharedRealm"

Comment: Right. I got confused regarding the ports. I'll look into this and edit my answer tomorrow when I'm back in the office.